# Imploding an array (MySQL query)

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL query selects data from the whole column instead of just a part of it (according to dropdown select sorting). I'm guessing it's due to the implode function. Is there a way to solve it? Maybe imploding after MySQL query would work? Any advices appreciated.

```
$weights = $_POST['pal_numb'];
       //var_dump($weights).'br';
       //array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } 
$weights = "'".implode("','",$_POST['pal_numb'])."'";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_table WHERE pal_numb in(".$weights.");");
       //var_dump($weights).'br';
       //array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } string(3) "'2'"
```

Comment: please, please, please, stop using `mysql`. It is far outdated. Use `mysqli` or even better (imo) `PDO`, and DO NOT put user input directly into a query!!!! Use prepared statements, my goodness!!

Comment: So what exactly is acting not as expected, again?

Comment: Like I said, it selects extra data from the column, in fact, the whole column instead of part that is needed. It is obvious in var_dump comments.

Comment: Smells like SQL injection to me!

Comment: I'm not too worried about outdated syntax or SQL injections as this application is going to be used on a local machine, but anyway, thanks for your valuable inputs!

Answer (score -1):

$weights = $_POST['pal_numb'];

$weights = "'".implode(',',$_POST['pal_numb'])."'";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_table WHERE pal_numb in(".$weights.");");

its will solve your problem.

Comment: And you open up your website for SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

What the ...

```
$weights = "'" . implode("','", $_POST['pal_num']."'";
```

You are telling implode to separate the array items with ',' rather than just ,. Use this instead

```
$weights = "'" . implode(',', $_POST['pal_num'] . "'";
```

Comment: Not too sure what the down votes are about, but that's OK. One thing I must point out is that the value being passed via $_POST['pal_num'] likely is a string and implode is expecting an array so this will fail.

Comment: Downvote was for not understanding the problem. SQL IN LIST takes a variable number of values. If the values are strings, then each value should be enclosed in quotes. Hence imploding with "','" instead of just "," (as you've suggested) and then starting and ending the results of the imploded with a quote. End result is: WHERE IN pal_numb in( 'first','second',third','fourth',...,'?'). The implode is correct for building the IN LIST. The bigger problem, as vbence has pointed out, is the risk of SQL injection.